# CSV export is missing data in one of the columns

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a csv file that this script works fine on.

```
$CCure = Import-csv C:\Scripts\file1.csv

ForEach ($user in $CCure) {

    [string]$1Name = $User.FirstName
    [string]$2Name = $User.LastName
    [string]$GivenName = $1Name.Split(" ")[0]
    [string]$SN = $2Name.Split(",")[0]
    [string]$ID = $User.ObjectID
    [string]$EmpID = $User.Int5 |   
    Select @{Name="First Name";Expression={$GivenName}}, @{Name="Last Name";Expression={$SN}}, @{Name="CCure ObjectID";Expression={$ID}}, @{Name="CCure Int5 Row";Expression={$EmpID}} | 
    Export-csv C:\Scripts\CCure\CCure-Names-Test.csv -Append -notypeinformation
    }
```

However, when I try a similar script going out to AD and want to use RegEx, things don't work. It seems to hang or when it does run, the SurName is missing. Why doesn't the second one work? I must be missing something simple?

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))" -properties samaccountname,givenname,sn
ForEach ($User in $Users) {

    [string]$1Name = $User.GivenName
    [string]$2Name = $User.SN
    [string]$GivenName = $1Name.Split(" ")[0]
    [string]$SN = $2Name.Split(",")[0] |
    Select @{Name="First Name";Expression={$GivenName}}, @{Name="Last Name";Expression={$SN}},@{Name="SID";Expression={$User.samaccountname}}| Export-Csv C:\scripts\ccure\AD-Active-Names3.csv -NoTypeInformation -append

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second example `$sn` would be null. This is because of the trailing pipe character that you have. This issue is also present in your first code block for `$EmpID`. The last command `Export-CSV` returns nothing to the output stream so the variable in both cases would be `$null`.

You are taking the result of `$2Name.Split(",")[0]` and sending that into the pipeline which is then left unused for `Select-Object`.

So the simple answer is remove the pipeline character and those two lines will now work separately.

```
[string]$SN = $2Name.Split(",")[0] 
Select @{Name="First Name";Expression={$GivenName}}, @{Name="Last Name";Expression={$SN}},@{Name="SID";Expression={$User.samaccountname}}| Export-Csv C:\scripts\ccure\AD-Active-Names3.csv -NoTypeInformation -append
```

Also consider making your own object if you are changing property names and values that much. This should accomplish the same thing, be easier to read and take advantage of the pipeline.

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))"
$Users | ForEach-Object {
    $props = @{
        "First Name" = ($_.GivenName).Split(" ")[0]
        "Last Name" = ($_.SurName).Split(",")[0]
        "SID" = $_.samaccountname
    }

    New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $props    
} | Select-Object "First Name","Last Name",SID |  Export-Csv C:\scripts\ccure\AD-Active-Names3.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

You will note that I used `$_.SurName` as the property names used since PowerShell AD Objects do not directly match their LDAP attribute names. If you tried to access `$_.SN` you would get a null value. `GivenName`,`Surname` and `SID` are part of the value set returned by default so you don't *need* to request them.

Looking at [about_ActiveDirectory_ObjectModel](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh531528(v=ws.10).aspx) you will see under AdUser:

> Surname - A property of type System.String, derived from the directory      attribute: sn

You will still get errors with this if Surname or GivenName are not populated. Accounting for that would be a simple if statement if that is going to be an issue.

Comment: Strange, I'm getting an error You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Scripts\CCure\Get-AD-Names.ps1:6 char:5
+     $props = @{
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: @MarcGel Please read my updated answer with tweaked code. Sorry about that. Ahkk...I have some null fields in my AD. If you don't you should be fine. Perhaps we should account for that.

Comment: @MarcGel Added a technical reference to the mapping I was talking about.

Comment: Still getting same errors. There are over 21k user objects so I'm using -properties samaccountname,givenname,sn but are you saying I need surname? I tried that too and still no go.

Comment: I am going to change the code to add more steps to help me with debugging.

Comment: @MarcGel try running the debug code and tell me where it fails. It only pulls 20 records now for testing. You have null values somewhere.

Comment: It's working thanks! For some reason, my $Users variable was holding only the Distinguished name. That's why everything was null. Restarted powershell ISE and back in business.